# MYSQL fulltext search with ö/oe

Tags: mysql, full-text-search, diacritics

There's a table

```
...
bez varchar(130)    latin1_german2_ci
...
```

Index

```
bez     FULLTEXT
```

I have a query with WHERE like this:

```
WHERE MATCH(bez) AGAINST(CONVERT('+moebius' USING latin1) COLLATE latin1_german2_ci IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

in results there are several rows:

Die Möbius Affäre
Moebius: Empire Rising - Detektiv Mystery Thriller Adventure
Silent Möbius Episode 1-26

But when I use

```
WHERE `bez` LIKE '%moebius%'
```

in results is see rows:

Moebius: Empire Rising - Detektiv Mystery Thriller Adventure
Moebius, die Lust, das Messer

Why the row "Moebius, die Lust, das Messer" is not found in fulltext search??
I broke my mind

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to get is called a *character expansion* in collations. I don't think they are supported unless you use character set `utf8` or `utf8mb4` with collation `utf8_unicode_ci` or `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`.

Read [_general_ci Versus _unicode_ci Collations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html)

Comment: But in results there're rows both with Moebius and Möbius words. But another row Moebius, die Lust, das Messer is not in results